# Billiard power and direction algorithm

Tags: vector-spaces, algorithms, power-series, game-theory, mahalanobis-distance

[Board clear Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp9aI.gif)
[Board with 2 sample shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot1g2.jpg)

> Important: White ball and black ball are exactly one(1) pixle not bigger

Hello.
I want to write algorithm that computer play billiard and hit specific ball in the current table for example

```
dimensions [3, 2]
White ball position: [1, 1]
Black ball position: [2, 1]
Hit power(distance): 4
```

White ball can shot in 7 direction vector

> [1, 0], [1, 2], [1, -2], [3, 2], [3, -2], [-3, 2], and [-3, -2]

**As specific examples, the shot at bearing [1, 0] is the straight line horizontal shot of distance 1, the shot at bearing [-3, -2] bounces off the left wall and then the bottom wall before hitting the black ball with a total shot distance of sqrt(13), and the shot at bearing [1, 2] bounces off just the top wall before hitting the black ball with a total shot distance of sqrt(5)**

Is there any algorithm to find hitting direction and give final position?

Comment: What does hitpower do? Is it the maximum distance? Also, your dimensions and positions do not match the linked image?!

But typically, bouncing could be simulated by flipping the board and continuing your directional vector, if that helps.

Comment: @Pieter21 yes this is distance. New image added I want to find all possible direction

Comment: @Pieter21 I understand the mirror. Do I need to continue with 3*h an 4*h  depend on distance?

Comment: You have 'mirrors' at 2*h, 4*h etc. (Only the even multiples)

Comment: @Pieter21 OK understand. I can make this answers [-2.-1]-[1,1] = [-3,-2],[2,1]-[1,1]=[1,0],[2,-1]-[1,1] = [1,-2] what is about? [1,2],[3,2],[3,-2],...

Comment: @Pieter21 Could you help me please?

Comment: What help do you still need? Please modify your question to denote what you understand and know now, and what are your new questions.

Comment: @Pieter21 I can not understand [2*h ±± x, 2*w ±± y] like virtual ball positions. And I can not find   [1,2],[3,2],[3,-2],

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate a mirroring solution.

If [x,y] is the coordinate of the black ball, then [-x, y], [x, -y], [-x, -y] are virtual black ball positions that would cause a hit with bounces.

Depending on 'distance', and table 'height' h, 'width' w, you may need to extend the virtual ball positions with [2*h $\pm$ x, 2*w $\pm$ y] like virtual ball positions, to allow bouncing multiple times on long/short edges.

Check if the distance to the white ball and angle from white to black (virtual) ball is allowed.

In your second example, a virtual black ball is positioned at [2, -1], and the direction is [2, -1] - [1, 1] = [1, -2], is in your list.

Comment: Depend on new position of black 2*2-2 = 2 and 3*2-1 = 5 therefore [2,5] = new black ball position but [2,5] - [1,1] = [1,4] and this is not in the answer. Do am I wrong?

Comment: You found the direction to the bottom right that uses two bounces, but that direction is not in your solution set. I added an example calculation.

Comment: OK understand. I can make this answers [-2.-1]-[1,1] = [-3,-2],[2,1]-[1,1]=[1,0],[2,-1]-[1,1] = [1,-2] what is about? [1,2],[3,2],[3,-2],...